# RSL used in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, rsl

How to use RSL(Runtime shared library) in flex ?
how can decrease loading time of swf using rsl? 
please give answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK default setting of the project is RSL.

check here *Goto Project->Properties choose the Library path from the tab where you can see the framework linkage*.

The thing is It is one of the way to reduce the size of the application and the library files are downloaded and saved to cache file in browsers. so when you run the application again, the library files are taken from the browser cache.so the loading makes faster than the first time.It continues until the cache is cleared from the browser. for more information [refer here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_02.html).